# For loops and inputing data?

Tags: c++, file, loops, input, for-loop

trying to figure out how to make a little inventory program and I can't for the life figure out why it isn't working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct record
{
    int item_id;
    string item_type;
    int item_price;
    int num_stock;
    string item_title;
    string item_author;
    int year_published;
};

void read_all_records(record records[]);
const int max_array = 100;
int main()
{
    record records[max_array];
    read_all_records(records);

    cout << records[2].item_author;
    return 0;
}

void read_all_records(record records[])
{
    ifstream invfile;
    invfile.open("inventory.dat"); 
    int slot = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count<max_array; count++);
    {
        invfile >> records[slot].item_id >> records[slot].item_type >> records[slot].item_price >> records[slot].num_stock >> records[slot].item_title >> records[slot].item_author >> records[slot].year_published;
        slot++;
    }
    invfile.close();

}
```

I'm testing it by having it print the second item from records author. When I run it, it doesn't show the authors name at all. The .dat file is located in just about every folder where the project is (I forgot which folder it needs to be in) so it's there.
The issue isn't that the file isn't working. It's the array not printing off anything. 
my inv file is basically:

123456
book
69.99
16
title
etc
etc

and repeats for different books/cds etc all on one line, all without spaces. Should just next in.

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see that the file is open.

```
invfile.open("inventory.dat"); 
if (!invfile.is_open())
  throw std::runtime_error("couldn't open inventory file");
```

You should check to seen that your file reads are working and breaks when you hit the end of file.

```
invfile >> records[slot].item_id >> records[slot].item_type ...
if (invfile.bad())
  throw std::runtime_error("file handling didn't work");
if (invfile.eof())
  break;
```

You probably want to read each record at time, as it isn't clear from this code how the C++ streams are supposed to differentiate between each field.

Usually you'd expect to use `std::getline`, split the fields on however you delimit them, and then use something like `boost::lexical_cast` to do the type parsing.

Comment: Just edited and put in the .dat file. It basically is line by line, no spaces. So the splicing isn't needed. I put the check in, and still nothing comes out.

Answer (score 0):

Add a little check:

```
 if (!invfile.is_open()) {
  cout<<"file open failed";
  exit(1);
 }
```

So that way, you don't need to copy your input file everywhere like you do now ;-)
You are reading in a specific order, so your input file should have the same order and required number of inputs.

You are printing 3rd element of the struct records. So you should have at least 3 records. I don't see anything wrong with your code. It would a lot easier if you can post your sample input file.

Comment: Wouldn't it be !invfile ? From what I see it will proc the cout when it is open.

Comment: No. is_open() returns true if the file has been opened successfully.

Comment: Right. is_open returns true when it is actually opened. So then the if statement would print "file open failed" when it opens. Correct?

Comment: So in that case the file is working but not outputting the one I need.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I think I'd structure it quite a bit differently.

First, I'd overload `operator>>` for a `record`:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, record &r) { 
    // code about like you had in `read_all_records` to read a single `record`
    // but be sure to return the `stream` when you're done reading from it.
}
```

Then I'd use an `std::vector<record>` instead of an array -- it's much less prone to errors.

To read the data, I'd use `std::istream_iterator`s, probably supplying them to the constructor for the `vector<record>`:

```
std::ifstream invfile("inventory.dat");

std::vector<record> records((std::istream_iterator<record>(invfile)),
                             std::istream_iterator<record>());
```

In between those (i.e., after creating the file, but before the vector) is where you'd insert your error handling, roughly on the order of what @Tom Kerr recommended -- checks for `is_open()`, `bad()`, `eof()`, etc., to figure out what (if anything) is going wrong in attempting to open the file.

Comment: This is a bit over my head... not really sure what to do there. This isn't for school so It's not like I just need this to work, I actually want to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: @Nogg: I should add one other point: I think I'd supply a full (absolute) path to a copy of the file I knew existed. This gives much better assurance of opening the file than just scattering copies everywhere and hoping it finds one of them.

Comment: @Nogg: just give the full path to the file. E.g. on Linux it'll be something like "/usr/me/projects/inventory/inventory.dat". On Windows, probably more like: "C:\\projects\\inventory\\inventory.dat". If you use back-slashes on Windows, you need to double each. Though they're not used as often, you can use normal slashes on Windows if you prefer. In that case, you don't need to double them like you do backslashes.